# Suppose $x \in X$ is a unit vector such that $||A|| = ||Ax||$; show that $A^TAx = ||A||^2 x$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, inner-products, matrix-norms

Let $X$ be a linear space with real Euclidean structure. Let $A : X \to X$ be a linear
map. Suppose $x \in X$ is a unit vector such that $||A|| = ||Ax||$; show that $A^TAx = ||A||^2 x$.

I tried in this way, considering $g(t)=||\frac{A(x+ty)}{||x+ty||}||$. It has a maximum at $t=0$ because of the definition of the norm of the matrix. Hence we get $g'(0)=0$. Now can I use this data to work with transpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $g(t) = \frac12\frac{ \|A(x+ty)\|^2 } { \|x+ty\|^2 }$, i.e., take the square of your original function.
Then $g'(t)=0$, where
$$
g'(t) = \frac{ y^TA^TA(x+ty) } { \|x+ty\|^2 }
-\frac{ \|A(x+ty)\|^2  } { \|x+ty\|^4 } y^T(x+ty).
$$
Hence
$$
g'(0) =  y^TA^TAx 
- \|Ax\|^2  y^Tx.
$$
This is zero for all $y$, hence
$$
A^TAx = \|Ax\|^2  x.
$$

Comment: I was trying in this way but I was stuck in the calculation of $g'(t)$. Can you please guide on how you did the differentiation? Probably the approach of calculating the $g'(t)$ where $g(t)$ is a fraction of two norms is unknown to me.

Comment: When I calculated to get your result I think we have to consider $<x,y>=<y,x>$ and $<Ax,Ay>=<Ay,Ax>$ and I think that it is true because $X$ is real space. Am I correct?

Comment: @Ri-Li yes, this is correct

Answer (score 2):

$$\|A^{T} Ax-\|A||^{2}x\|^{2}$$ $$=\|A^{T} Ax\|^{2}-2\|A||^{2} \langle A^{T}Ax, x \rangle+\|A\|^{4}$$ $$=\|A^{T} Ax\|^{2}-\|A\|^{4}.$$ Now  $\|A^{T} Ax\| \leq \|A^{T}\|\|A\|=\|A\|^{2}$ so we get $0 \leq \|A^{T} Ax-\|A||^{2}x\|^{2} \leq 0$

Comment: Sir, I upvoted your answer. Both of the solutions are correct but I accepted the other answer as that aligned with my try but I indeed say that your answer is the elegant one.

Comment: No problem with that. I am  glad that you got an answer to your question.